# CRM 2011: SDK Install Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, wif

I have this problem while trying to install the SDK for Visual Studio 2012.
I have tried installing Windows Identity Foundation, but I get a message saying "this upgrade is not necessary". It is installed on Windows 7 by default isn't it?
I am busy installing Visual Studio 2010 for use in the meantime.
What can be done about this?
[image]

Comment: WIF was moved to the core .NET 4.5 library, in the System.IdentityModel namespace, so you don't have to install anything anymore.

Comment: In Windows 8 WIF must be activated in "Programs and Features"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Identity Foundation is not installed by default on Windows 7, you need to download and install from this site:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331

From the site: For Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, select the msu file with name starting Windows6.1 (x64 for 64bit and x86 for 32bit)